# Checking for featured image or content image

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm trying to write a function that will check if the featured image is used or if the following function catches the first image:

**Catch the first image in the post**

```
function catch_that_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches [1] [0];
  $rooturi = get_theme_root_uri();

  if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
    $first_img = "$rooturi/reverie-master-child/img/default_image_bv_logo.jpg";

  }
  return $first_img;
}
```

My progress so far. Trying to return the featured image if it's used - if it's empty use the function above to catch the first image

```
function check_image_used() {
    $featured_used = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
    $content_image = catch_that_image();

    if (empty($featured_used)) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this resource: https://www.gavick.com/magazine/wordpress-quick-tip-4-automatically-set-the-first-post-image-as-a-featured-image.html

```
function auto_featured_image() {
    global $post;

    if (!has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
        $attached_image = get_children( "post_parent=$post->ID&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&numberposts=1" );

      if ($attached_image) {
              foreach ($attached_image as $attachment_id => $attachment) {
                   set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $attachment_id);
              }
         }
    }
}
// Use it temporary to generate all featured images
add_action('the_post', 'auto_featured_image');
// Used for new posts
add_action('save_post', 'auto_featured_image');
add_action('draft_to_publish', 'auto_featured_image');
add_action('new_to_publish', 'auto_featured_image');
add_action('pending_to_publish', 'auto_featured_image');
add_action('future_to_publish', 'auto_featured_image');
```